# Should I make a new Repo method?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, repository

I am wondering sometimes how should I be making my repo methods.

I have this

```
 public List<TableA> Get(Guid id)
    {
        return session.Query<TableA>().Where(x => x.Id== id).ToList();
    }
```

Now I use this in a couple places in my service layers but in one place I need to do a select.

Should I do this

```
public List<string> GetNames(Guid id)
    {
        return session.Query<TableA>().Where(x => x.Id== id).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    }
```

OR

//this is in my service layer

```
public void ServiceGet(Guid id)
{
     myRepo.Get(id).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
}
```

I am never sure if I should be making a new method or just return some general results and then let the service layer deal with filtering it down.

Comment: Looks like you're using `ToList` to early.  Why not return the result of the `Where` instead and then you can append the `Select` or do a `ToList` after the method is called.

Comment: @ juharr - I guess that would save having to do the ToList again but besides that should I be making seperate methods for stuff like this or is it just send back general results and let them do the selects and more filtering down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let your database do as much filtering as possible because that's what it's good at. When it comes time to do performance tweaking, this will give you the most flexibility. The tricky part is drawing the fine line between filtering and business logic.

Comment: Methinks you didn't understand the question.

Comment: @Jason: What makes you say that?

Comment: I read the question as: Is it better to filter at the repo layer or service layer? My answer is repo.

Comment: @ Michael Valenty - Yes basically that is what I am asking. Is it better to just return a general result and let the service layer filter it down or should you just keep creating methods that return specialized results back(like for instance one column )